# What does this hvmloader.c bootloader code do?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, real-mode

I read the code of xen and find the code below. But I don't know the meaning of it. Is it the code which initializes `idt` and `gdt`? Is it the code that jumps from real mode to protected mode? If it is, where is the physical address of `gdt` and `idt`?
Hvmloader.c :

```
asm (
    "    .text                       \n"
    "    .globl _start               \n"
    "_start:                         \n"
    /* C runtime kickoff. */
    "    cld                         \n"
    "    cli                         \n"
    "    lgdt gdt_desr               \n"
    "    mov  $"STR(SEL_DATA32)",%ax \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%ds                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%es                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%fs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%gs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%ss                \n"
    "    ljmp $"STR(SEL_CODE32)",$1f \n"
    "1:  movl $stack_top,%esp        \n"
    "    movl %esp,%ebp              \n"
    "    call main                   \n"
    /* Relocate real-mode trampoline to 0x0. */
    "    mov  $trampoline_start,%esi \n"
    "    xor  %edi,%edi              \n"
    "    mov  $trampoline_end,%ecx   \n"
    "    sub  %esi,%ecx              \n"
    "    rep  movsb                  \n"
    /* Load real-mode compatible segment state (base 0x0000, limit 0xffff). */
    "    mov  $"STR(SEL_DATA16)",%ax \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%ds                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%es                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%fs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%gs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%ss                \n"
    /* Initialise all 32-bit GPRs to zero. */
    "    xor  %eax,%eax              \n"
    "    xor  %ebx,%ebx              \n"
    "    xor  %ecx,%ecx              \n"
    "    xor  %edx,%edx              \n"
    "    xor  %esp,%esp              \n"
    "    xor  %ebp,%ebp              \n"
    "    xor  %esi,%esi              \n"
    "    xor  %edi,%edi              \n"
    /* Enter real mode, reload all segment registers and IDT. */
    "    ljmp $"STR(SEL_CODE16)",$0x0\n"
    "trampoline_start: .code16       \n"
    "    mov  %eax,%cr0              \n"
    "    ljmp $0,$1f-trampoline_start\n"
    "1:  mov  %ax,%ds                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%es                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%fs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%gs                \n"
    "    mov  %ax,%ss                \n"
    "    lidt 1f-trampoline_start    \n"
    "    ljmp $0xf000,$0xfff0        \n"
    "1:  .word 0x3ff,0,0             \n"
    "trampoline_end:   .code32       \n"
    "                                \n"
    "gdt_desr:                       \n"
    "    .word gdt_end - gdt - 1     \n"
    "    .long gdt                   \n"
    "                                \n"
    "    .align 8                    \n"
    "gdt:                            \n"
    "    .quad 0x0000000000000000    \n"
    "    .quad 0x008f9a000000ffff    \n" /* Ring 0 16b code, base 0 limit 4G */
    "    .quad 0x008f92000000ffff    \n" /* Ring 0 16b data, base 0 limit 4G */
    "    .quad 0x00cf9a000000ffff    \n" /* Ring 0 32b code, base 0 limit 4G */
    "    .quad 0x00cf92000000ffff    \n" /* Ring 0 32b data, base 0 limit 4G */
    "    .quad 0x00af9a000000ffff    \n" /* Ring 0 64b code */
    "gdt_end:                        \n"
    "                                \n"
    "    .bss                        \n"
    "    .align    8                 \n"
    "stack:                          \n"
    "    .skip    0x4000             \n"
    "stack_top:                      \n"
    "    .text                       \n"
    );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like most of the work is setting the CPU back to real mode to jump to the BIOS restart address (16 bytes before the end of real mode memory = 0xFFFF0). The real work is done in main, which is called about a third of the way down. As for the rest of the details, I'll leave that to someone who knows something about this kind of stuff.

Comment: For those who are interested, here's the source file from Xen that contains this code: http://svn.openfoundry.org/xenids/xen-4.0.0/tools/firmware/hvmloader/hvmloader.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the beginning of the code:

`cld` - clear direction flag.

`cli` - clear interrupt flag to mask interrupts.

`lgdt gdt_desr` - loads the value of `gdt_desr` into `gdt`. Look for `gdt_desr` in the source code to find out the value loaded to `gdt`.

```
"    mov  $"STR(SEL_DATA32)",%ax \n"
"    mov  %ax,%ds                \n"
"    mov  %ax,%es                \n"
"    mov  %ax,%fs                \n"
"    mov  %ax,%gs                \n"
"    mov  %ax,%ss                \n"
```

Store the value `STR(SEL_DATA32)` into `ax`, and then from `ax` to `ds`, `es`, `fs`, `gs` and `ss` (to all segment registers except `cs`).

```
"    ljmp $"STR(SEL_CODE32)",$1f \n"
```

Does a long jump / far jump to `STR(SEL_CODE32):0x1f`, practically sets `cs` to `STR(SEL_CODE32)` and `eip` to `0x1f`.

If this is a a 32-bit code segment, the processor goes into 32-bit protected mode. See [Stackoverflow question: bootloader - switching processor to protected mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211541/bootloader-switching-processor-to-protected-mode). However, I don't see here the code used to set the `PE` bit of `cr0` register as in the above example and in [Wikipedia article on protected mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Entering_and_exiting_protected_mode).

After that line of code `cs:eip` moves to that address (`STR(SEL_CODE32):0x1f`) not shown in this piece of code, so I can't say what happens then. It may continue on the next line too if `cs:eip` points there (if that's the jump address). Anyway, the rest of the code and comments looks like the code used to switch from protected mode back to real mode.

Intruction `lidt 1f-trampoline_start` loads the value of `1f-trampoline_start` into `idt`, so to get to know the actual value used, search the source for `if-trampoline_start`.